# Detect all processes are running in monit

Tags: monit

I'd like to run a script from monit after the status of all files/processes/file systems are accessible/running. Outside of writing a script to parse the output of `monit status` and `monit summary`, is there some functionality that would allow me to do this?

Answer (score 0):

The way I've decided to accomplish this is run the script outside of monit and use the `monit validate` utility. This can be run whether or not the monit daemon is running and its exit status `$?` is `1` if it does nothing and `0` if it detects something is not running/accessible. It can also be run even if the monit daemon is not accessible from the command line (i.e. if you're not allowing localhost) or monit is not running in daemon mode.